# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<models.Person>

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, jax-rs

I have written a jersey REST API method which returns a list of persons which is queried from mysql backend using hibernate. Here is the method

```
    @Path("Person")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public List<Person> person()
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
        List persons =  cr.list();
        GenericEntity<List<Person>> list = new GenericEntity<List<Person>>(persons) {};
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return persons;

    }
```

and here is my `MessageBodyWriter`

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Person> {

@Override
public long getSize(Person arg0, Class<?> arg1, Type arg2, Annotation[] arg3, MediaType arg4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return -1;
}

@Override
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2, MediaType arg3) {
    return Person.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
}

@Override
public void writeTo(Person person, Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] arg3, MediaType arg4,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> arg5, OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.write(person.toString().getBytes());
    }

}
```

When i make a get request to the above method i am getting 
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List.
can someone please help me get through with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What I've always done in this case is make a Persons object that contains the List of persons. There may be a better way but if your under a time crunch and want to get it done then this should work. If it doesn't work then my guess that no JSON marshalling is working, in which case you have a configuration problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Persons
{
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Person> getPersons()
    {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons)
    {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
}
```

Comment: u want me to return an instance of the Persons class ?

Comment: Yes. Change List<Person> person() to Persons person()

Comment: You might want to remove your message body writer that you have configured and let the default one handle it. Also, are you able to get any other json responses to work? For instance if you just return a string does it return a JSONified version of the string?

Comment: It looks like your client is requesting a text/plain media type and not json. You might want to ensure you Accept Header in your request is application/json.

Comment: I wrote my message body writer because jersey was complaining that the message body writer isn't present , and yeah returning a string is giving me a json version of the string.

Comment: i did that in post man , i set the accept header to application/JSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97663/discussion-between-kumard-and-josh-chappelle).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is quite an old question - However, there is an excellent solution to this now. Whenever you wish to return a list of objects, you can utilise the below code:

```
List<KaggleFileResponse> data = kaggleService.listFiles(xxxx);
GenericEntity<List<KaggleFileResponse>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<KaggleFileResponse>>(data) {};
return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_OK).entity(entity).build();
```

The code converts the list into a generic entity that can be written back.